# HQL JOIN QUERY: could not resolve property:

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, hql

I am getting the following error when I try to execute a join query

```
("could not resolve property: Countries of: com.fexco.helloworld.web.model.Customer [select cus from com.fexco.helloworld.web.model.Customer as cus join cus.Countries as cou where cus.id = cou.id]")
```

I am trying to join the Customer and Countries tables together by a common id

Customer.hbm.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping package="com.ccg.db.test">
<class name="Customer" table="Customer">
    <id name="id" column="id" type="bigiint">
        <generator class="native"/>
    </id>
    <property name="firstname" type="string" >
       <column name="firstname" /> 
    </property>
    <property name="surname" type="string" >
        <column name="surname" /> 
    </property>
    <property name="address1" type="string" >
        <column name="address1" /> 
    </property>
    <property name="address2" type="string" >
        <column name="address2" /> 
    </property>
    <many-to-one name="Countries" column="id" class="Countries" /> 
</class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Countries.hbm.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"   "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping package="com.ccg.db.test">
<!-- CLASS NAME MIGHT BE CUSTOMER -->
<class name="Countries" table="Countries">
    <id name="id" column="id">
        <generator class="native" />
    </id>
    <property name="country" column="country" />
</class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

And this is the query that i am trying to call

```
String sql_query = "select cus from Customer as cus join cus.Countries as cou where cus.id = cou.id";
```

I am new to HQL so not sure about everything with it yet so does anybody know how to solve this?

Thanks

Comment: If you start with Hibernate I recommend using Java Classes with @Entity annotations to build your Hibernate stuff. I don't know how the .xml stuff handle the parameters. -- Does the db schema look like you expect it?

Comment: I am using that in my classes, i have it accessing the database, reading and writing and all that, just trying to get this JOIN QUERY working is the problem

Comment: does the DB Schema look like you expect it? (does Hibernate correctly create a DB Schema?)

Comment: ya is does, thats all ok

Answer (score 1):

It's cus.countries, not cus.Countries. Property names are case sensitive.

Comment: tried that and it didnt work... but i have it declared as Countries, so it shouldnt matter should it?

Comment: in the class Customer, you probably have something like getCountries and setCountries. That means that the property is countries (with lower case). You should change Customer.hbm.xml to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
select cus from Customer cus  where cus.id = cus.countries.id
```

Comment: is your variable name `Countries`? then use `cus.Countries.id`